# Image processing: vectorize numpy array elements substitution

Tags: python, performance, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

The code works well but is very slow. How can I vectorize the color substitution to avoid usage of Python `for` loop?

```
processed_image = np.empty(initial_image.shape)
for i, j in np.ndindex(initial_image.shape[:2]):
    l_, a, b = initial_image[i, j, :]
    idx = mapping[a + 128, b + 128]
    a, b = new_colors[tuple(idx)]
    processed_image[i, j] = l_, a, b
```

I have an image `initial_image` in CIELAB space as numpy array of shape *(some height, some width, 3)*. I need to produce a corrected image by changing *a* and *b* color components of image using `mapping`. `mapping` is a numpy array of shape *(255, 255, 2)*. It gives me indices which can be used to get corrected *a* and *b* colors from `new_colors`. `new_colors` is of shape *(table height, table width, 2)*.

Solutions that use scikit-image will also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use advanced indexing:

```
# chain the two maps
chained = new_colors[(*np.moveaxis(mapping, 2, 0),)]
# split color channels
c1, *c23 = np.moveaxis(initial_image, 2, 0)
# add 128
c23 = *map(np.add, c23, (128, 128)),
# apply chained map
processed_image_2 = np.concatenate([c1[..., None], chained[c23]], axis=2)
```

Comment: Works at least 100 times faster for me!

Comment: Does `None` mean `np.newaxis` here?

Comment: @SashaTsukanov yes, they mean the same. As a matter of fact I think `np.newaxis` is just an alias for `None`.